# Test with Kotlin Coroutines is randomly failing

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, mocking, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

Let us suppose we have a class member whose purpose is
to bring 2 objects (let's say **object1** and **object2**) from two different places and then create the final
result merging these two object in another one, which is finally returned.

Suppose then the operation of retrieving **object1** and **object2** can be done *concurrently*,
so this leads to a typical use case of kotlin coroutines.

What has been described so far is shown in the following example:

```
fun parallelCall(): MergedObject {
    return runBlocking(context = Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            val object1 : Deferred<Object1> = async {
                bringObject1FromSomewhere()
            }
            val object2 : Deferred<Object2> = async {
                bringObject2FromSomewhere()
            }

            creteFinalObject(object1.await(), object2.await())

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw ex
        }
    }
}
```

The surrounding try block should intercept any kind of exception thrown while
**object1** and **object2** are retrieved, as well as in the `createFinalObject` method.

This latter simply merges together the awaited results from previous calls,
waiting for both of them to be accomplished.
Note that the awaiting of the deferred object1 and object2 happens almost at the same time,
since they are both awaited when passed as arguments to the `createFinalObject` method.

In this scenario I can perform a test using *mockk* as mocking library such that whenever `bringObject1FromSomewhere()`
throws an exception, then the `creteFinalObject` method is **NEVER** called. Namely, something like:

```
@Test
fun `GIVEN bringObject1FromSomewhere throws exception WHEN parallelCall executes THEN creteFinalObject is never executed`() {
      every { bringObject1FromSomewhere() } throws NullPointerException()
      every { bringObject2FromSomewhere() } returns sampleObject2

      assertThrows<NullPointerException> { parallelCall() }

      verify(atMost = 1) { bringObject1FromSomewhere() }
      verify(atMost = 1) { bringObject2FromSomewhere() }
      //should never be called since bringObject1FromSomewhere() throws nullPointer exception
      verify(exactly = 0) { creteFinalObject(any(), any()) }
  }
```

The problem is that the test above works almost always, but, there are some cases in which it *randomly fails*,
calling the `createFinalObject` method regardless of the mocked values.

Is this issue related to the slight difference in time in which the deferred object1 and object2
are awaited when `creteFinalObject(object1.await(), object2.await())` is called?

Another thing which comes to my mind could be the way in which I am expecting argument in the last line of the test:
`verify(exactly = 0) { creteFinalObject(any(), any()) }`
does *mockk* could have any problem when `any()` is used?.

Further, can potentially be an issue the fact that the `try { }` block is not able to detect the exception
before the `createFinalObject` method is called? I would never doubt about this in a non-parallel environment but probably
the usage of **runBlocking** as coroutineScope changes the rule of the game?
Any hints will be helpful, thanks!

**Kotlin version**:1.6.0  **Corutines version**: 1.5.2  **mockk version**: 1.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it fails because it attempts to call the `creteFinalObject` function? Because when reading your code, I think that should be impossible (of course, never say never :D). The `creteFinalObject` function can only be called if both `object1.await()` and `object2.await()` return successfully.

I think something else is going on. Because you're doing 2 separate async tasks (getting object 1 and getting object 2), I suspect that the ordering of these 2 tasks would result in either a success or a failure.

Running your code locally, I notice that it sometimes fails at this line:

`verify(atMost = 1) { bringObject2FromSomewhere() }`

And I think there is your error. If `bringObject1FromSomewhere()` is called *before*  `bringObject2FromSomewhere()`, the exception is thrown and the second function invocation never happens, causing the test to fail. The other way around (2 before 1) would make the test succeed. The `Dispatchers.Default` uses an internal work queue, where jobs that are cancelled before they are even started will never start at all. And the first task can fail fast enough for the second task to not being able to start at all.

I thought the fix would be to use `verify(atLeast = 0, atMost = 1) { bringObject2FromSomewhere() }` instead, but as I see on the MockK GitHub issues page, this is not supported (yet): https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/806

So even though you specify that `bringObject2FromSomewhere()` should be called at **most** 1 time, it still tries to verify it is also called at **least** 1 time, which is not the case.

You can verify this by adding a delay to the async call to get the first object:

```
val object1 : Deferred<Object1> = async {
    delay(100)
    bringObject1FromSomewhere()
}
```

This way, the test always succeeds, because `bringObject2FromSomewhere()` always has enough time to be called.

So how to fix this? Either hope MockK fixes the functionality to specify `verify(atLeast = 0, atMost = 1) { ... }`, or disable the verification on this call for now.